# Unable to get Quicksand.js working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to filter collections of data using [quicksand.js](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/). However, I'm having problems getting my data to appear. I have been able to get the data to disappear. Yet, it won't re-appear. I've created a jsfiddle, which is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0t5r9yvy/). Basically, my JavaScript looks like this:

```
var $content = $('#stage');
var $data = $content.clone();

function filterData(tag) {
  var data = [];
  if (tag === null) {
    data = $data.find('li');
  } else {
    data = $data.find('li[data-tags=' + tag + ']');
  }

  console.log(data);
  $content.quicksand(data, {
    duration: 800,
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
  });
  return false;
}
```

Everything looks correct to me. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your fiddle is broken.  One, you link `quicksand 1.3` and pair it with a recent jquery version it doesn't support.  Two, you call out the `easeInOutQuad` without linking the `jquery.easing.1.3.js`.  Three, you have scope issues, the `filterData` function is not defined globally.

Your real problem, though, is this line in the documentation:

`attribute – attribute containing unique value able to identify same item within source and destination collection, default: 'data-id'`

None of your "stage" data `li`s have this attribute so it won't filter them properly.  Add it and all seems to work:

```
<ul id="stage">
  <li data-tags="A" data-id="1">Item A-1</li>
  <li data-tags="A" data-id="2">Item A-2</li>

  <li data-tags="B" data-id="3">Item B-1</li>
  <li data-tags="B" data-id="4">Item B-2</li>
</ul>
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0t5r9yvy/1/).